# Android: Fetch the very first value in JSON data using Retrofit Library

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am using the `Retrofit` Library in Android to read the `JSON` data.
I want to only read the country names from the below `JSON` i.e just the value. Is it possible to read such `JSON` data using `Retrofit` Library?

```
{
    "China": ["Guangzhou", "Fuzhou", "Beijing"],
    "Japan": ["Tokyo", "Hiroshima", "Saitama", "Nihon'odori"],
    "Thailand": ["Bangkok", "Chumphon", "Kathu", "Phang Khon"],
    "United States": ["Mukilteo", "Fairfield", "Chicago", "Hernando", "Irving", "Baltimore", "Kingston"],
    "India": ["Bhandup", "Mumbai", "Visakhapatnam"],
    "Malaysia": ["Pantai", "Kuala Lumpur", "Petaling Jaya", "Shah Alam"]
}
```

Comment: I will never understand why some people send *data* as the key... I mean, this is a list masquerading as a map. Now you'll have to parse it manually from `JsonObject`.

Comment: This is the type of JSON format I am getting online, so in order to save my time I wanted to use the same using retrofit library.

Comment: I think the best you can do is [`Call<JsonObject>` from GSON.](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = iter.next();
    list.add(key); 
    try {
        Object value = json.get(key);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // Something went wrong!
    }
}
   Log.d("TAG",list.toString());
```

Comment: I know it can be done using this approach. I was finding a way to do it using Retrofit Library. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

for example :

```
public class Country{
    private List<String> name;

}
```

An associative array translates to a Map in Java:

```
Map<String, Country > countries = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String, Country >>(){}.getType());
```

in retrofit just add to model class:

```
@Expose
 private Map<String, Country> result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>` as retrofit result obj and get the keys.

or just get it with string then cast it to hasmap

```
 val typeToken: Type = object : TypeToken<HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>()
        {}.type
 val result = Gson().fromJson<HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>(tmp, typeToken)
```

then you can iterate trough the keys.